# Lubuntu not showing up on boot

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

The problem is Lubuntu is not shown on boot after a fresh install, only Windows gets started. Installed both of them via USB.

[Here is the boot-repair report](https://pastebin.com/dp9HRdev)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of UEFI:

- You've installed Windows 10 in UEFI mode
- You've installed Lubuntu in BIOS mode

So the options are:

- Reinstall lubuntu in UEFI mode
- go to the UEFI firmware and choose BIOS boot mode and boot off HD2 to boot lubuntu.